Shikaku grid deduction puzzle

Japanese publisher Nikoli produces this geometric logic puzzle. Can you divide this grid into rectangular and square pieces such that each piece contains exactly one number and each number reflects its piece’s area?
Please show all your workings and how you arrived at the answer. Just giving the answer is not enough.
Source: futilitycloset.com

Here's the solution!

 


Step-by-step:
1.

To start, simply drawing lines between numbers, as they must of course be separate areas







Considering the 6 on the left, it can go at most 1 cell up, so has to go at least 4 cells down. The same logic can be applied to the 5 next to it, which also must be walled off on the right hand side as well.

Now look at the 4 top left, in row 2. It must be a 2x2 square, as there is no room for  rectangle. This then solves the 5 and 2 beneath it.







 The 16 top right has to be a 4x4 square, as there is no room for a 2x8 rectangle. As there is only one 4x4 possible, it can be filled in.

The 7 on the right hand edge must extend down and can now be filled in too.

In the top left, the 4 must extend at least one more to the right.







The bottom left cell can only be reached by the 2 above it, so that must be the complete area. This then means the cell above that 2 must be part of the 6 further up, and the left hand column is completed.







With similar logic, the remaining cells bottom left must be part of the 12, and a rectangle can be drawn. We now see the 16 in the middle cannot be a 4x4, so must be a 2x8. Only one of these is possible, so it can be filled in.

The 6 and 9 bottom right now only have one possible solution, and the 2 to the left and the 2 above the 16 are also completed.







Finally, on the right, the 2s are the only numbers that can reach the remaining cells in the penultimate column so they can be filled. This completes the 4 to the left as a 2x2 square, which forces the 5 in the middle to go straight up to the top - which inadvertently also completes the 4 to the left of it.

 For the remaining 3 numbers, the 3 must go up and hence also down, which leaves only one possible solution for the 4 and 2 beneath it.

Which gives us the final solution!



